# Error:Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file.Try supplying a main-dex list. # methods: 72477 > 65536

Tags: android, android-multidex

I want to add fused location services but it shows me some error.
Help me.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.adil.bloodbankapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.joielechong:countrycodepicker:2.1.5'
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.2.4'
    compile 'hanks.xyz:htextview-library:0.1.5'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please choose an answer to make it easier for future visitors.

Answer (score 630):

None of the answers they gave you was exhaustive.
The problem lies in the Multidex.
You must add the library in the app gradle :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

After, add in the defaultConfig of the app gradle :

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Your Application must be of the Multidex type..
You must write it in the manifest :

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

"MyApplication" must be either the Multidex class, or it must extend it.

Comment: So `MyApplication extends android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication` ?

Comment: I have tried this solution, but I end up with this new problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49518115/android-studio-3-1-warning-the-rule-keep-public-class-extends-java-lang-anno?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @ban-geoengineering Yes, you can extend the MultidexApplication :)

Comment: Here's the official android doc page providing more explanations on the why this happens and how to make a better release-version apk: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: it's not a good method to solve the issue, better to remove unused code and libraries, refactor your project code

Comment: You should avoid multidex at all if possible. Please see my answer below.

Comment: It is not really true. You can't afford not to create some extra abstraction just because you should be careful not to be able to use it. On medium-large projects this consideration is not good

Comment: @user25 Why is this not a good solution what are side effects we may not know from using multiDex ?

Comment: This works with `minSdkVersion 21` even without the `MyApplication` thing

Comment: not having 80000 methods would be a fine solution if googles libraries didn't have 80000 methods(whole reason why they added multidex was because their own services library they wanted everyone to use had tens of thousands of methods).

Comment: for androidx add:
     implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1

Comment: if your minSdkVersion is 21 or higher, the multidex support library is not needed.

Comment: I used minSdkVersion 19 and then use Android Studio Emulator API 19 runs cannot run google Ads and then use Emulator API 22 will have Build Output saying Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 87528 > 65536) . Using Emulator API 29/33 has not problem.  Why will the emulator API 22 cannot even build when I changed the AppSingleton to MultiDexApplication ? I have already enable MutliDex in gradle and add the dependency.

Comment: I give up and changed minSdkVersion from 19 to 21 and retry. Then the Emulator Pixel 4 API 22 can build and debug properly. I dont know if it is emulator problem as I dont have an API 22 mobile to test.

Answer (score 299):

I fixed my problem with the solution below:

### In Gradle build file, add dependency:

> implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

### And then in the "defaultConfig" section, add:

> multiDexEnabled true

Comment: Worked for me. Detailed instructions on configuration here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle

Comment: Enabling multidex support is not necessary in most applications. You should consider removing the unused libraries, please see my answer below.

Comment: I wanted to avoid multidex in my react-native app by reducing the number of methods, so I used https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts to measure them. Turns out facebook's methods alone are 27k+, but I must have Fb, etc almost no method count is my code, so multidex is a must

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'

Answer (score 163):

modify your app's or module's `build.gradle`

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 <----- *here
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true <------ *here
    }
    ...
}
```

According to official documentation

> **Multidex support for Android 5.0 and higher**
>
> Android 5.0 (API level 21)
> and higher uses a runtime called ART which natively supports loading
> multiple DEX files from APK files. ART performs pre-compilation at app
> install time which scans for classesN.dex files and compiles them into
> a single .oat file for execution by the Android device. Therefore, if
> your minSdkVersion is 21 or higher, ***you do not need the multidex
> support library.***
>
> For more information on the Android 5.0 runtime, read ART and Dalvik.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: If you upgrade the min version to 21 I don't think is necessary to add the line `multiDexEnabled true`

Comment: I can confirm that it is indeed *NOT* needed to add `multiDexEnabled true` if you upgrade the min version to 21.

Comment: Yes, see https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-on-l

Answer (score 94):

**What are dex files:** Android app (APK) files contain executable bytecode files in the form of Dalvik Executable (DEX) files, which contain the compiled code used to run your app.

**Reason for this exception:** The DEX specification limits the total number of methods that can be referenced within a single DEX file to 65,536 (64K reference limit) —including Android framework methods, library methods, and methods in your own code.

**Step 01. Add the following dependency as follows**

**For Non-Androidx Users,**

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true  //ADD THIS LINE
}
```

**For Androidx Users,**

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true  //ADD THIS LINE
    }
```

**Step 02:**

**After adding those Sync projects and before you run the project make sure to Build a project before the run. *otherwise, you will get an exception.***

Answer (score 60):

You can follow [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex).

Versions of the platform prior to Android 5.0 (API level 21) use the Dalvik runtime for executing app code. By default, Dalvik limits apps to a single classes.dex bytecode file per APK. In order to get around this limitation, you can add the multidex support library to your project:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

If your minSdkVersion is set to 21 or higher, all you need to do is set multiDexEnabled to true in your module-level build.gradle file, as shown here:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This works for me. Just multiDexEnabled + dependency (without class extending as in other answers). Also works for minSdkVersion 16.

Answer (score 45):

when you are using dependencies so your methods increased!
google has a solution for that. that called Multidex!

**NOTE: be sure that min SDK is over 14.**

**in your build.gradle :**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}



  dependencies {
      implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    }
```

**FOR androidX USE :**

```
 def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
 implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version'
```

---

For more information please go to the orginal link :

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: Great solution! fixed my problem

Answer (score 39):

**I used below solution in my Flutter project:**

Open `yourproject/app/build.gradle` and add the following lines:

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        
        minSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

then

```
dependencies {
    ...

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

If you have migrated to `AndroidX`, you will want this instead:

```
dependencies {
    ...

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

This solution worked for me. Thank you for asking this question.

Comment: Thanks. But even without adding the dependency, it worked for me

Answer (score 36):

Hi problem is here remove it

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
```

why?

**Note:** Don't use the combined play-services target. It brings in dozens of libraries, bloating your application. Instead, specify only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses.

And use what you need.https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Like for location service

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0
```

For Cloud Messaging

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0
```

Comment: yup now I am facing problem my run button has disabled.

Answer (score 31):

If you are building **DEBUG APK**, just add:

```
debug {
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
```

inside `buildTypes`

and if you are building **RELEASE APK**, add
`multiDexEnabled true` in release block as-

```
release {
                ...
                multiDexEnabled true
                ...
        }
```

Comment: Open project/app/build.gradle and add the following lines. defaultConfig {
    ...

    multiDexEnabled true
}

Answer (score 27):

**For flutter projects** you can also solve this issue

open your \android\app\build.gradle

you sould have the following:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28

    }

}
```

If your minSdkVersion is set to 21 or higher, all you need to do is set **multiDexEnabled to true** in the defaultConfig. Like this

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true 

    }

}
```

if your minSdkVersion is set to 20 or lower add **multiDexEnabled true** to the defaultConfig

And define the implementation

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'// or 2.0.1
}
```

At the end you should have:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true  // added this
    }

}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

For more information read this:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Answer (score 24):

I solved my same problem like this way, you need to follow 2 simple step. I'm **AndroidX** user so for me, first I implement this dependencies in **build.gradle** file in my project in dependencies section.

`implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'`

```
dependencies {
//for multidex
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

}

after add this dependencies in your **build.gradle** file then **sync** your project again

Now add in the "**defaultConfig**" section:

**multiDexEnabled true**

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.papel.helper"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    multiDexEnabled true
  
}
```

Now Rebuild your project again and Run :)

Comment: For me, `implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'` isn't necessary (Android studio 4.1.1). It's enough `multiDexEnabled true`.

Comment: The trick is the newer multidex library version

Answer (score 19):

Just do the following:

> build.gradle

```
(module:app)


android {
            ....
      defaultConfig {
              multiDexEnabled true // enable mun
      }
}
```

And add below dependency in your `build.gradle` app level file

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 19):

I found this solution for my project
I just set the minimum SDK version to **21** and that solves my problem

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 //set the minimum sdk version 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
    }
    ...
}
```

if your minSdkVersion is **21** or higher multidex is enabled by default, and you do not need the multidex support library.
To read more about multidex https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Answer (score 17):

In Gradle build file, add dependency:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
```

or

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

or

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.0'
```

And then in the "defaultConfig" section, add:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Under targetSdkVersion

```
minSdkVersion 17
targetSdkVersion 27
multiDexEnabled true
```

Now if you encounter this error

Error:Failed to resolve: multidex-instrumentation Open File

You need to change your gradle to 3.0.1

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

And put the following code in the file gradle-wrapper.properties

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

Finally

add class  Applition in project  And introduce it to the AndroidManifest
Which is extends from MultiDexApplication

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate( ) {
        super.onCreate( );
    }
}
```

Run the project first to create an error, then clean  the project

Finally, Re-launch the project and enjoy it

Comment: I still have "Failed to resolve: multidex-instrumentation"

Answer (score 17):

**Just add this code in your app's or module's build.gradle**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        
        multiDexEnabled true <------ * here
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Please try adding this in your app defaultConfig {}.This help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 14):

This will do the work either for Kotlin or Java project.

Step 1 - Locate **build.gradle(Module:app)** under the Gradle Scripts

Step 2 - add **multiDexEnabled true** see below:

```
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.appname"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true //addded
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Step 3 - add the multidex dependency

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.0' //added
}
```

Finally, sync your project.. Enjoy!

Answer (score 13):

If you are using minifyEnabled with Proguard, you likely won't need to enable multi-dex.  I agree with MG Developer that you should try to avoid multi-dex if possible.  My solution was to enable multi-dex only for debug builds.  minifyEnabled solves the problem for release builds

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        // getting error: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file.  # methods: 65537 > 65536
        // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex
        // minifyEnabled true (used with release) will fix this by getting rid of unused method calls, but this will hide debugging info on crash
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: what are some of the drawbacks of using multidex if we have to ?

Comment: Very good question, which I don't really have an answer to.  Read the following if you haven't:
at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle

It seems like for API >= 21, there's not much issue.  For < 21, seems Android has to do some fancy footwork that could potentially have issues.  Since many people do need to turn this on, my guess is that Android has got it working well, so I wouldn't worry about it too much.  I just like to be conservative where possible.

Answer (score 11):

1. Goto build.gradle of app folder,
2. set minSdkVersion to 21

Save and Run your app, it should run without the dex error now

Answer (score 10):

You have too many methods count.
Android dex file has a limit of 65536 methods you are allowed to have.

For starters, if you don't need all of google play services API and just the location, replace

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
```

with

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
```

You can refer to this page for ways to avoid it or if needed to allow more: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: yup but its not that real problem. I think i am adding same dependencies. One for Firebase and other one for location Check bellow two lines.

Answer (score 10):

I have no idea why, maybe it is because I develop in Kotlin but to fix this error 
I finally have to create a class that extends `MultiDexApplication` like this:

```
class MyApplication : MultiDexApplication() {
}
```

and in my `Manifest.xml` I have to set

```
<application
        ...
        android:name=".MyApplication">
```

to not confuse anyone, I also do:

```
multiDexEnabled true
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

for androidx, this also works for me:

```
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
```

...

`<application android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">`

does not work for me

Comment: remember to do project clean and rebuild after setting multiDexEnabled true. This fixed it for me.

Comment: changing the application name attribute in the manifest didn't work for me either, but enabling multiDex in the gradle build file and adding the implementation did work. It seems that it's optional to change the manifest name tag now?

Answer (score 9):

**add your file *android/app/build.gradle***

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ubicacion"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true // ✔
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

All I had to do was set the Minimum SDK Version to 21 in File > Project Structure > App > Flavors

Answer (score 5):

I have encountered this error twice and the solution for this is; Check you app gradle file to see your target SDk, if it is 20 or higher, just add one line to your `defaultconfig { multiDexEnabled true }`

Else if your targetSDK is less than 20, add the line to your defaultConfig and also add a dependency

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'.
```

Check this link for more.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle

Answer (score 5):

Using multidex support should be the last resort. By default gradle build will collect a ton of transitive dependencies for your APK.  As recommended in [Google Developers Docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#avoid),  first attempt to remove unnecessary dependencies from your project.

Using command line navigate to Android Projects Root.
You can get the compile dependency tree as follows.

```
gradlew app:dependencies --configuration debugCompileClasspath
```

You can get full list of dependency tree

```
gradlew app:dependencies
```

[image]

Then remove the unnecessary or transitive dependencies from your app build.gradle. As an example if your app uses dependency called 'com.google.api-client' you can exclude the libraries/modules you do not need.

```
implementation ('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.28.0'){
   exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
   exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
   exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core'
   }
```

Then in Android Studio Select Build > Analyze APK...
Select the release/debug APK file to see the contents. This will give you the methods and references count as follows.

[image: Analyze APK]

Comment: what are some of the drawbacks of using multidex if we have to

Answer (score 2):

In build:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.proyecto.marketdillo"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dev.khamsat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Comment: this was enough for me too.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the number of class dependencies you have in your app Gradle file. If the classes exceed 72,400, you might want to use multidex as a solution to better handle file indexing. Findout more from here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Answer (score 0):

After suffering for two hours found the solution.

File path: android/build.gradle

Worked for me

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.something"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true --> This works for me
}
```

***If your minSdkVersion is set to 21 or higher, multidex is enabled by default and you do not need the multidex support library.*** - Reference : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late for the answer, but, I am sure that this problem is caused by only a single dependency mostly, `'com.google.android.gms:play-services'`. Please read the full answer for better understanding of problem, and solution.

In my case, I was using `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'` which is the latest version of it, by the time I am writing this answer. It is having wayy too many method count.
My only motive to use it was, for ***fetching location from user's device***. Google recommends using `play-services-location` only for fetching location, so I did not want to replace this dependency for getting my work done.
So, after numerous google searches, I found,

> you can downgrade the version

to some previous stable version, to get your job done. And for my case, the best suited version for me came out to be `17.1.0`. So I recommend you to use this specific version only, if your usecase to use `play-services-location` is exactly like mine.

Do these changes

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
```

Nonetheless, there is always option to enable multidexing in your code, but, that is the most inefficient way to solve this problem IMO.

> If you can find the root cause of which dependency is maxing out your dex file size by large
> method count, then I guess you should tweak, or replace that
> dependency.

Comment: I solved this problem by upgrading my minimum sdk to level 21!

Comment: @keno Yeah, that is also a feasible solution.

Answer (score 0):

**If you use Dagger:**

```
public class App extends DaggerApplication {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this); //ADD MULTIDEX HERE!!!
    }

    @Override
    protected AndroidInjector<? extends DaggerApplication> applicationInjector() {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build();
    }
}
```

In app build.gradle file:

```
android {
        defaultConfig {
            ...
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
 ...
 implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your minsdk version  minSdk 24 or more..problem solved

Comment: I think as low as 21 will work.  This helped me.