# Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file due to google-play-service

Tags: android, google-play-services, wear-os

Trying to add an ad to our existing Android app, and when compiled I got this:

```
Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file. Try supplying a main-dex list.
```

Looking around, the suggestion is to reduce the play-services size and this is what I have:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1' // newly added
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

I use Android Wear in the code, so when I reduce to:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:12.0.1'
```

Now I got:

```
resource style/Theme.AppCompat (...) not found.
```

I try adding

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
```

and I got more problems of conflict. What is my best solution? My current fix is to change AppCompat back to Activity. Would appreciate other answers!

Answer (score 8):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249633/errorcannot-fit-requested-classes-in-a-single-dex-file-try-supplying-a-main-dex?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Try adding this library in the app gradle: `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'`. Then add `multiDexEnabled true` in the defaultConfig of the app gradle. Also from this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html), when your app and the libraries it references exceed 65,536 methods, you encounter a build error that indicates your app has reached the limit of the Android build architecture.