# Error: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 67593 > 65536)

Tags: android, android-studio

How to solve this error I'm getting in Android Studio:

> Error: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 67593 > 65536)

cant build my project now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249633/errorcannot-fit-requested-classes-in-a-single-dex-file-try-supplying-a-main-dex answer to your issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file.Try supplying a main-dex list. # methods: 72477 > 65536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249633/errorcannot-fit-requested-classes-in-a-single-dex-file-try-supplying-a-main-dex)

Answer (score 3):

Do this **4** step

**1**: Add this library in dependencies of the app build.gradle :

`implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'`

**2**: Add in the defaultConfig of the app build.gradle :

```
defaultConfig {
    //other configs
    multiDexEnabled true //add this line
}
```

**3**: Create new Java class like this :

```
public class ApplicationClass extends MultiDexApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

**4**: Add this to your manifest (**in application tag**):

```
<application
    android:name=".ApplicationClass"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Answer (score 3):

Same situation happened in my Visual Studio 2019 Xamarin project, and the way to solve this problem is just like what mentioned in the link:
[Error:Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file.Try supplying a main-dex list. # methods: 72477 > 65536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249633/errorcannot-fit-requested-classes-in-a-single-dex-file-try-supplying-a-main-dex)

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

By checking the Enable multiDex checkbox in the option page of the ***.Droid project solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Before you take any decision, as said in Google documentation :

> Before configuring your app to enable use of 64K or more method
>   references, you should take steps to reduce the total number of
>   references called by your app code, including methods defined by your
>   app code or included libraries.

So try to remove useless importation in your app gradle and do a nice clean project or do multidex

Source : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex