# Android: Firestore fails with "Found conflicting setters with name: setWallpaper"

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Don't be quick to judge based on the title alone, I know similar questions have been asked before but this problem is a little different. Please bear with me and read through.

So I have defined a `BaseUser` class as follows:

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Exclude;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class BaseUser
{
    private static final String TAG = "BaseUser";

    /**
     * Firebase Authentication and Database
     */
    protected FirebaseAuth auth;
    protected FirebaseFirestore db;
    protected FirebaseStorage st;

    /**
     * General BaseUser Info
     */
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<String> phones;
    private List<String> emails;
    private List<AddressLocation> addresses;

    public BaseUser()
    {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        st = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        phones = new ArrayList<>();
        emails = new ArrayList<>();
        addresses = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    /**
     * Getters
     */

    public final String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public final String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Exclude
    public final List<String> getPhones()
    {
        return phones;
    }

    @Exclude
    public final List<String> getEmails()
    {
        return emails;
    }

    @Exclude
    public final List<AddressLocation> getAddresses()
    {
        return addresses;
    }

    /**
     * Special Getters
     */

    @Exclude
    public final String getPhone(int index)
    {
        return phones.get(index);
    }

    // SimilarStuff


    /**
     * Setters
     */

    @Exclude
    public final void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Exclude
    public final void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Exclude
    public final void setPhones(List<String> phones)
    {
        this.phones = phones;
    }

    @Exclude
    public final void setEmails(List<String> emails)
    {
        this.emails = emails;
    }

    @Exclude
    public final void setAddresses(List<AddressLocation> addresses)
    {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    /**
     * Special Setters
     */

    @Exclude
    public final void addPhone(String phone)
    {
        this.phones.add(phone);
    }

    // SimilarStuff

    /**
     * Authentication
     */
    @Exclude
    public final boolean isLoggedIn()
    {
        assert(auth != null);
        return (auth.getCurrentUser() != null);
    }

    /**
     * Shared BaseUser Instance
     */

    protected static BaseUser holder = new BaseUser();

    @Exclude
    public static BaseUser getInstance()
    {
        assert(holder != null);
        return holder;
    }

    /**
     * Database
     */

    @Exclude
    protected final void downloadUser(final Callable<Void> callback)
    {
        // Doesn't get called for now.
    }

    @Exclude
    protected final void uploadUser()
    {
        assert(isLoggedIn());
        db.collection("users").document(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).set(this).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
            {
                Log.wtf(TAG, "Failed to write user data");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

as you can see, the class defines a couple of strings along with a couple of Arrays. And includes absolutely nothing else that might have `setWallpaper`. Also, as you can see, as an effort to locate the source of the error I've literally excluded all functions (yes, even if they do not start by `set` or `get`) except for the two functions that read the two simple strings.

Now when the `uploadUser` method gets called I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Found conflicting setters with name: setWallpaper (conflicts with setWallpaper defined on android.content.ContextWrapper)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.0.0:632)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.0.0:348)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.0.0:169)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.access$300(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.0.0:53)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.0.0:774)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.0.0:170)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.access$300(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.0.0:53)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.0.0:774)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.0.0:170)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.access$300(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.0.0:53)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.0.0:774)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.0.0:170)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.0.0:101)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.0.0:77)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.convertAndParseDocumentData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.0.0:216)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseSetData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.0.0:75)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.0.0:174)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.0.0:153)
        at com.companyname.projectname.authentication.SignupActivity$6$1$1.onComplete(SignupActivity.java:297)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I grepped my folder to find out what includes `setWallpaper` and I found the following:

```
shell$ grep -rnw "setWallpaper" .
Binary file ./authentication/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/AppName/debug/0/com/companyname/projectname/authentication/ResetPasswordActivity.class matches
Binary file ./authentication/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/AppName/debug/0/com/companyname/projectname/authentication/WelcomeActivity.class matches
Binary file ./authentication/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/AppName/debug/0/com/companyname/projectname/authentication/SignupActivity.class matches
Binary file ./authentication/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/AppName/debug/0/com/companyname/projectname/authentication/LoginActivity.class matches
Binary file ./authentication/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRun/AppName/debug/0/com/companyname/projectname/authentication/PhoneVerificationActivity.class matches
Binary file ./authentication/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/AppName/debug/265/com/companyname/projectname/authentication/LoginActivity.dex matches
Binary file ./authentication/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/AppName/debug/265/com/companyname/projectname/authentication/WelcomeActivity.dex matches
Binary file ./authentication/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/AppName/debug/265/com/companyname/projectname/authentication/PhoneVerificationActivity.dex matches
Binary file ./authentication/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/AppName/debug/265/com/companyname/projectname/authentication/ResetPasswordActivity.dex matches
Binary file ./authentication/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/AppName/debug/265/com/companyname/projectname/authentication/SignupActivity.dex matches
Binary file ./authentication/build/intermediates/transforms/dexMerger/AppName/debug/1/classes.dex matches
```

So `BaseUser` has absolutely nothing to do with this `setWallpaper` thing. It's only related to my UI Activities (and I do not explicitly use it anyway).

### What I've tried:

1. Excluding everything except for 2 setters for simple Strings, as mentioned above.
2. I thought maybe having the `BaseUser` class itself deal with Firestore is causing problems, so I tried doing the same from outside the class. Same.
3. I tried Firebase Database rather than Firestore. Same.
4. There're other classes that inherit `BaseUser`. I've disabled all of them. Same. (I'm not even sure why that would be a problem!)

### Extra Info

I'm not sure if the following is relevant, but considering the weird nature of the error, I'm just going to throw it here anyway.

The class `BaseUser` is in a separate module called `user`. The UI classes that deal with authentication (and listed in the `grep` output above) are in a separate module called `authentication`. A third module `core` defines the firebase library dependencies and the necessary info from `google-services.json`.

I must also mention that with this configuration of modules I can use Firebase Authentication just fine. Only Firestore or Firebase Database have issues.

### Question

Now why on earth is Firestore complaining about a setter that's not even in my class? How do I fix this?

### Edit 1

I tried two different things now:

I tried uploading a simple map instead, so inside the `uploadUser` function I added the following:

```
protected final void uploadUser()
{
    assert(isLoggedIn());
    Map<String, Object> city = new HashMap<>();
    city.put("name", "Los Angeles");
    city.put("state", "CA");
    city.put("country", "USA");
    db.collection("users").document(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).set(city);
}
```

Which worked fine, Then I tried adding a simple class as the object to upload. as follows:

```
protected final void uploadUser()
{
    class Stupid {
        public String name;
        public String email;

        public Stupid()
        {
        }

        public Stupid(String name, String email)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getEmail()
        {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email)
        {
            this.email = email;
        }
    }
    Stupid stupid = new Stupid("Name", "Email");
    db.collection("users").document(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).set(stupid);
}
```

Which again, gave me the same error with `setWallpaper`. I also tried another variant of the Stupid class with ints rather than strings. Also same. A stupid simple POJO class. What is wrong with this whole thing?! I used to use classes and objects with Firebase database all the time before. What am I missing in this case?

Comment: Have you tried to simply change the name of the method to something else? Do you get the same error?

Comment: If you mean the `uploadUser` function then yes, tried that. No effect.

Comment: The problem is, I had an almost identical class in a previous project, I used it with Firebase database all the time, and I never had to deal with any of this stupid stuff. It also had private members, public setters and getters with the same naming conventions, etc. So I really don't get what's missing or wrong in this case.

Comment: Have you tried to set the values directly onto public fields?

Comment: Tried it in the `Stupid` class in Edit 1 part. Whether the member variables are public or private with getters and setters didn't change anything. I also tried printing the member variables themselves right before uploading them to make sure they're OK as expected, and they were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I did two things, not sure which of them fixed it (maybe both?!)

Previously, I was checking for google play services availability. So, for that, I included `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0`. Which caused me to get the error `Error: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file. Try supplying a main-dex list. # methods: 72477 > 65536`. My solution was to add `multiDexEnable 'true'`. What I did now was follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48249683/2328163) instead. So I removed all the multi dex stuff and used `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0` instead.

The second thing I did was disable instant run.

Now, the same code I have works like a charm and is able to read/write in Firestore.

I do not have any explanation for what was going on. But the problem is now gone.