# Ideas on "Error: Type com.google.firebase.iid.zzav is referenced as an interface from com.google.firebase.messaging.zzd"?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Getting an error when running on Api 22 and Api 23. 24 and up work fine. Any ideas why? The internet seems to not have an answer to this one yet.

Error: Type com.google.firebase.iid.zzav is referenced as an interface from `com.google.firebase.messaging.zzd`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like your Firebase dependencies don't match.  Make sure all of them match the latest versions shown in the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).

Answer (score 2):

I have also face this error which I solved by updating the version of **firebaseMessagingVersion** to **20.1.6** which was **20.1.2**

If you are using a capacitor (ionic) you also need to update **build.gradle** file likewise from location '\node_modules@capacitor\android\capacitor\build.gradle'

I hope this will help to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the Multidex. You must add the library in the app gradle :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

After, add in the defaultConfig of the app gradle :

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Your Application must be of the Multidex type.. You must write it in the manifest :

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

"MyApplication" must be either the Multidex class, or it must extend it.

Thanks for fix;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49645970/13066825