# Cordova stopped building after the 23rd April 2020 Firebase update

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a large Ionic 4 Cordova project that was working fine and all, no new plugins installed in the past 3+ months.

It seems to happen almost every time Google decides to update Firebase that breaking changes occur and everything is messed up (at least twice a year).

This just happened, one moment I was building the project and after 5 minutes, I did another build with nothing changed other than some Typescript code and everything was broken (see part of the output below). When I looked at the build output, it seems clear that it's another Firebase issue out of nowhere (April 23rd update), but this one seems to break a lot of things, not just Firebase plugin (such as D8: Type `libcore.io.Memory` was not found).

What can be done about this? It no longer works with or without Firebase plugin. I've tried reinstalling platform and plugins, removing Firebase plugin (then it builds with warnings but crashes when running on Android device).

Here is the cordova build output:

```
> Transform firebase-components.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-components:16.0.0) with AarTransform
C:\Users\Alex\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\logback-android-1.1.1-9.aar\51e60d380335f3685f5a1101dad723a0\jars\classes.jar: D8: Type `javax.mail.Session` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `javax.mail.Session ch.qos.logback.core.net.SMTPAppenderBase.buildSessionFromProperties()`
C:\Users\Alex\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\logback-android-1.1.1-9.aar\51e60d380335f3685f5a1101dad723a0\jars\classes.jar: D8: Type `javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `java.util.List ch.qos.logback.core.net.SMTPAppenderBase.parseAddress(java.lang.Object)`
C:\Users\Alex\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\logback-android-1.1.1-9.aar\51e60d380335f3685f5a1101dad723a0\jars\classes.jar: D8: Type `javax.mail.Transport` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void ch.qos.logback.core.net.SMTPAppenderBase.sendBuffer(ch.qos.logback.core.helpers.CyclicBuffer, java.lang.Object)`
C:\Users\Alex\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\jetified-OneSignal-3.12.5.aar\2eea1bc86b246d6dff65f246f31aa6a5\jars\classes.jar: D8: Type `com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `java.lang.String com.onesignal.PushRegistratorGCM.getToken(java.lang.String)`
C:\Users\Alex\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\jetified-OneSignal-3.12.5.aar\2eea1bc86b246d6dff65f246f31aa6a5\jars\classes.jar: D8: Type `com.amazon.device.iap.model.ProductDataResponse$RequestStatus` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.onesignal.TrackAmazonPurchase$1.<clinit>()`
C:\Users\Alex\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\jetified-OneSignal-3.12.5.aar\2eea1bc86b246d6dff65f246f31aa6a5\jars\classes.jar: D8: Type `com.amazon.device.iap.PurchasingService` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.onesignal.TrackAmazonPurchase.setListener()`
C:\Users\Alex\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\jetified-OneSignal-3.12.5.aar\2eea1bc86b246d6dff65f246f31aa6a5\jars\classes.jar: D8: Interface `com.amazon.device.iap.PurchasingListener` not found. It's needed to make sure desugaring of `com.onesignal.TrackAmazonPurchase$OSPurchasingListener` is correct. Desugaring will assume that this interface has no default method.
D8: Type com.google.firebase.iid.zzbb is referenced as an interface from `com.google.firebase.messaging.zzf`.
C:\Users\Alex\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-perf-18.0.1.aar\1e031eabd958cc0ab81ebdf85ab8b818\jars\classes.jar: D8: Interface `org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler` not found. It's needed to make sure desugaring of `com.google.firebase.perf.network.zzg` is correct. Desugaring will assume that this interface has no default method.
C:\Users\Alex\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-clearcut-17.0.0.aar\af0f9e57669d7078b1fd93f7fc9cfade\jars\classes.jar: D8: Type `libcore.io.Memory` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.android.gms.internal.clearcut.zzfd$zzb.zza(long, byte)`
C:\Users\Alex\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-analytics-impl-17.0.0.aar\908f2a155e513a3bbdab69fcd257de70\jars\classes.jar: D8: Type `libcore.io.Memory` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.android.gms.internal.gtm.zztx$zza.zza(long, byte)`
C:\Users\Alex\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-analytics-impl-17.0.0.aar\908f2a155e513a3bbdab69fcd257de70\jars\classes.jar: D8: Type `libcore.io.Memory` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.android.gms.internal.gtm.zztx$zzb.zza(long, byte)`
C:\Users\Alex\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-clearcut-17.0.0.aar\af0f9e57669d7078b1fd93f7fc9cfade\jars\classes.jar: D8: Type `libcore.io.Memory` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.android.gms.internal.clearcut.zzfd$zza.zza(long, byte)`
> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug

C:\Users\Alex\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\okhttp-3.10.0.jar\824193bc6a837b6136115ba1f7c4a3e3\jetified-okhttp-3.10.0.jar: D8: Type `org.conscrypt.Conscrypt` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform.buildIfSupported()`
C:\Users\Alex\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-ads-base-18.0.0.aar\81d2cabfa68cdd92a98d540edee4d078\jars\classes.jar: D8: Type `libcore.io.Memory` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdqz$zzb.zza(long, byte)`
C:\Users\Alex\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-ads-base-18.0.0.aar\81d2cabfa68cdd92a98d540edee4d078\jars\classes.jar: D8: Type `libcore.io.Memory` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdqz$zza.zza(long, byte)`

> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebugcom.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\Alex\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\jetified-firebase-messaging-20.0.0.aar\640c3bfaa24224c1bd23d7784498c000\jars\classes.jar
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
        at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:420)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\Alex\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\jetified-firebase-messaging-20.0.0.aar\640c3bfaa24224c1bd23d7784498c000\jars\classes.jar
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:909)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.lambda$convertToDexArchive$6(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:834)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:124)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:101)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:904)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:70)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:43)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:94)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:99)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Type com.google.firebase.iid.zzbb is referenced as an interface from `com.google.firebase.messaging.zzf`.
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:89)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:60)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:64)
        ... 10 more




FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\Alex\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\jetified-firebase-messaging-20.0.0.aar\640c3bfaa24224c1bd23d7784498c000\jars\classes.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 59s
> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug FAILED
38 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 30 up-to-date
```

I attach the Ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.6 (C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.9.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.5
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : not installed
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 49 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.6.0
   native-run  : 0.2.2

System:

   NodeJS : v10.16.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.9.0
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Here is a list of installed plugins:

```
> cordova.cmd plugin ls
cc.fovea.cordova.purchase 8.1.1 "Purchase"
code-push 3.0.1 "CodePushAcquisition"
com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions 0.6.5 "Native Page Transitions"
cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release 4.0.0 "cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release"
cordova-android-support-gradle-release 3.0.1 "cordova-android-support-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-actionsheet 2.3.3 "ActionSheet"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 2.0.2 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 2.1.1 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.0.0 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-androidx 1.0.2 "cordova-plugin-androidx"
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter 1.1.0 "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-appavailability 0.4.2 "AppAvailability"
cordova-plugin-background-mode 0.7.3 "BackgroundMode"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.8 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-brightness 0.1.5 "Brightness"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.1.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-cocoapod-supportx 1.7.3 "Cordova CocoaPods Dependency Support"
cordova-plugin-code-push 1.12.0 "CodePush"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-device-motion 2.0.1 "Device Motion"
cordova-plugin-device-orientation 2.0.1 "Device Orientation"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.2 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.6.2 "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 8.1.1 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-gyroscope 0.1.4 "Device Gyroscope"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.1.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-iosrtc 5.0.0 "iosrtc"
cordova-plugin-is-debug 1.0.0 "IsDebug"
cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.2 "LocalNotification"
cordova-plugin-market 1.2.0 "Market"
cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation 3.0.1 "CDVBackgroundGeolocation"
cordova-plugin-media 5.0.3 "Media"
cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy 2.3.0 "Request Location Accuracy"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 3.0.2 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-vibration 3.1.1 "Vibration"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.6.0 "SocialSharing"
cordova-plugin-zip 3.1.0 "cordova-plugin-zip"
cordova-promise-polyfill 0.0.2 "cordova-promise-polyfill"
cordova-wheel-selector-plugin 1.0.0 "Cordova Wheel Selector Plugin"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 5.0.0 "Diagnostic"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.6.0 "OneSignal Push Notifications"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 8.1.0 "BarcodeScanner"
```

Here is the generated `project.properties` file showing the dependencies and version specs:

```
# This file was originally created by the Android Tools, but is now
# used by cordova-android to manage the state of the various third party
# libraries used in your application

# This is the Library Module that contains the Cordova Library, this is not
# required when using an AAR

# This is the application project.  This is only required for Android Studio Gradle projects

# Project target.
target=android-28
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release/global-cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-android-support-gradle-release/global-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
cordova.system.library.1=com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-plugin-badge/global-badge.gradle
cordova.system.library.2=androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
cordova.system.library.3=androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
cordova.gradle.include.4=cordova-plugin-local-notification/global-localnotification.gradle
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11+
cordova.system.library.5=androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
cordova.system.library.6=androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0
cordova.gradle.include.5=cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/global-dependencies.gradle
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+
cordova.system.library.8=androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
cordova.system.library.9=androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
cordova.system.library.10=androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0
cordova.gradle.include.6=phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/global-barcodescanner.gradle
cordova.system.library.11=androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
cordova.system.library.12=com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.12.5
cordova.system.library.13=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.+
cordova.system.library.14=com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.+
cordova.gradle.include.7=onesignal-cordova-plugin/global-build-extras-onesignal.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.8=cordova-plugin-code-push/global-build-extras.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.9=cordova-plugin-firebase-lib/global-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.15=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.+
cordova.system.library.16=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.+
cordova.system.library.17=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:18.+
cordova.system.library.18=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:18.+
cordova.system.library.19=com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4
cordova.system.library.20=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4
cordova.system.library.21=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1
cordova.system.library.22=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
cordova.gradle.include.10=cordova-plugin-googlemaps/global-tbxml-android.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.11=cordova-plugin-googlemaps/global-apikey.gradle
cordova.system.library.23=androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0
cordova.system.library.24=androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0
cordova.system.library.25=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1
cordova.system.library.26=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1
```

I am using the `cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release` https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release plugin that managed (until now) the play services versions for preventing such conflicts.

I have read this "duplicate question" but it does not solve the current problem as I already have multidex enabled in the project, and the issues are not related to the same Firebase update:

[Ideas on "Error: Type com.google.firebase.iid.zzav is referenced as an interface from com.google.firebase.messaging.zzd"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61239070)

Comment: Likely that's 2 plugins, which use incompatible library versions... whatever these "49 other plugins" might be.

Comment: This answer and the "duplicate question" does not however solve anything as the problems appeared without changing anything in the project. I also have multidex already enabled long ago.

Comment: It's quite duplicate and you've attached no code concerning the dependencies. If you don't have reproducible builds, which might use `+` for version numbers, this doesn't make it any less duplicate.

Comment: I attach information about the dependencies in my updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's a bit of trial and error with the versioning, the following combination of plugins has solved the problem by locking to a specific version for all other plugins that depend on google/firebase services:

- cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release (was already installed)
- cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release (was NOT installed)
- cordova-plugin-firebase-lib: https://github.com/wizpanda/cordova-plugin-firebase-lib (was already installed)

Answer (score 1):

it seems **firebase.core** not needed anymore, and you need to add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.6'`
as you'r missing it

[firebase release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

> The Firebase Android library firebase-core is no longer needed. This SDK included the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics.
>
> Now, to use Analytics or any Firebase product that recommends the use of Analytics (see table below), you need to explicitly add the Analytics dependency: com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.0.

Comment: When answering and using a link, please post the context of what's at the link as well as the link. If the link breaks over time, having the context in the answer will help future readers.

Comment: This sounds like something to dig in, though it would be normal to handle this via cordova instead of changing auto-generated configurations. In this case it's not clear which of the google dependencies could be causing breaking changes in the last update.