# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.android:support-v4:r7]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm a total Android / Java newbie, and came across a project I want to compile below:

https://github.com/maxamillion32/Android-Firebase-mapping

It is a bit old and maybe that's why it's causing me issues.

First error I got about Build Tools 24.0.1, which I downloaded. Now I get the following error which I cannot resolve:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.android:support-v4:r7] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I've checked my Dependencies in File>Project Structure and com.google.android:support-v4:r7 is there.

build.gradle (Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mimming.hacks.starter"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

//    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'

}
```

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gradle version used seems to be of lower version, in-order to use `implementation` gradle version should be above 3

1. You should replace your dependencies in build.gradle to latest version.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
```

2. Also you will have to upgrade the `distributionUrl` also

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

As you already mentioned you have updated the buildToolsVersion, this should work fine and also make sure all the dependencies are using  `implementation` and not `compile`as compile is deprecated.

Comment: thanks for your reply. unfortunately it doesn't work. I have updated my question with my gradle files. does it work for you? with current one I get

`Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
`

Comment: Add google() above jcenter() in both places in gradle

Comment: Thanks, that helped, however now I get ```Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 69769 > 65536)
``` I have amended my gradle files in the question. Any idea?

Comment: multiDexEnabled true you should use in your gradle and also add the dependency.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249633/errorcannot-fit-requested-classes-in-a-single-dex-file-try-supplying-a-main-dex check the link you will get solution:)