# Error: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 67451 > 65536)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

When i run The app i get this error 'Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 67451 > 65536)'
Help me.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ammora.kotgram"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

// To inline the bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into
// bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. (e.g. navArgs)

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
//adds
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'


testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error:Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file.Try supplying a main-dex list. # methods: 72477 > 65536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249633/errorcannot-fit-requested-classes-in-a-single-dex-file-try-supplying-a-main-dex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add multidex library

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

and  in build.gradle file, add this line

```
defaultConfig {
  ...
  multiDexEnabled true
  ...
}
```

after that,
create a class that extend MultiDexApplication.
override attachBaseContext and add

```
MultiDex.install(this);
```

the in manifest in application tag add

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```