# This Error will be shown when I'll try to run flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, build.gradle

**This error shown when after adding image picker and add some key to dist.plst in ios/runner this error I'll try hard to run it also I'm remove pubspec_analiyse.ymal first I'll think is this the
problem **

```
> D8:Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 88386 >
> 65536) com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error
> while merging dex archives:  The number of method references in a .dex
> file cannot exceed 64K. Learn how to resolve this issue at
> https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html    at
> com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:132)
>   at
> com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:119)
>   at
> com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
>   at
> com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:432)
>   at
> com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:242)
>   at
> org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:57)
>   at
> org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
>   at
> org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:67)
>   at
> org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
>   at
> org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
>   at
> org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
>   at
> org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
>   at
> org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
>   at
> org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:60)
>   at
> org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:200)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by:
> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to
> complete, position: null  at
> Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_2.1.62.java:0)     at
> com.android.tools.r8.utils.Y.a(SourceFile:78)     at
> com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:11)   at
> com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:117)
>   ... 36 more Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Cannot fit
> requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 88386 > 65536)     at
> com.android.tools.r8.utils.T0.error(SourceFile:1)     at
> com.android.tools.r8.utils.T0.a(SourceFile:2)     at
> com.android.tools.r8.dex.P.a(SourceFile:740)  at
> com.android.tools.r8.dex.P$h.a(SourceFile:7)  at
> com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(SourceFile:14)   at
> com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.b(SourceFile:25)   at
> com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(D8.java:133)    at
> com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(D8.java:1)  at
> com.android.tools.r8.utils.Y.a(SourceFile:36)     ... 38 more
> 
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>    > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
>      The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
>      Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
> 
> * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> 
> * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> 
> BUILD FAILED in 10s [!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the
> Java bytecode.
>     To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.
>     To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code Exception:
> Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 Exited (sigterm)
```

*I'll be thank for any one help me to solve this problem*

```
**This is the lib that I'll incloude it in pubspic**
```

1. cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
2. cloud_firestore: ^2.5.4
3. image_picker:^0.8.4+4
4. firebase_storage: ^10.0.6
5. random_string:^2.3.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error:Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file.Try supplying a main-dex list. # methods: 72477 > 65536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249633/errorcannot-fit-requested-classes-in-a-single-dex-file-try-supplying-a-main-dex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two solutions:

**Option 1:**

You need to target Android **21** as a `minSdkVersion` in `/android/app/build.gradle` file.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        minSdkVersion 21   //*** LOOK AT THIS LINE ***
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

You need to add `multiDexEnabled true` in `/android/app/build.gradle` file.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true   //*** LOOK AT THIS LINE ****
    }
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

More explanations [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/android)

Comment: Thanks Bro, It's working