# In Android Studio Run Flutter App Kotlin Version Error

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, build.gradle, version

In Android Studio Run the Flutter application This type of error after adding Kotlin new version in the android build gradle.
ERROR:D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 67426 > 65536)

Tools-> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin plugin Update,
and change Android level build.gradle  ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.10' but no result

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249633/errorcannot-fit-requested-classes-in-a-single-dex-file-try-supplying-a-main-dex) might help.

Comment: Find my solution:Configure your app for multidex
Note: If your minSdkVersion is set to 21 or higher, multidex is enabled by default and you don't need the multidex library.
If your minSdkVersion is set to 20 or lower, then you must use the multidex library and make the following modifications to your app project:

Modify the module-level build.gradle file to enable multidex and add the multidex library as a dependency, as shown here:  android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 33
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}